# Jquery Mobile Touch and release

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I currently stuck with jquery mobile touch and release, In jquery mobile how would i go about replacing a image src on touch event and then on release reapply the original image to src.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `touchstart` and `touchend` events. You can handle the event on the window object and then test if the target of the event is your image. If so replace the src of the image.

```
var normalPic = "http://lorempixel.com/180/180/food/1/";
var touchPic = "http://lorempixel.com/180/180/food/2/"

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $(window).on("touchstart mousedown",  function(e){
        var id = e.originalEvent.target.id;
        if (id && id == "theImage") {     
            $("#theImage").prop("src", touchPic);
        }
    });
    $(window).on("touchend mouseup dragend",  function(e){
        $("#theImage").prop("src", normalPic);
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/YX4QC/)**

You can also use jQM's vmousedown, vmouseup events (http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/) which abstract the mouse vs touch events:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#theImage").on("vmousedown",  function(e){
        $(this).prop("src", touchPic);
    });
    $("#theImage").on("vmouseup vmousecancel vmouseout",  function(e){
        $(this).prop("src", normalPic);
    });
});
```

> updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/YX4QC/1/)**